dig SERVFAIL with powerdns and docker
I'm trying to setup a containerised version of powerdns recursor in my LAN but am having some trouble.
The resolver is on 192.168.1.88 and is directly connected to my router.
I have it setup to it will only accept queries from one host on 192.168.1.80.
This is my docker-compose:
services:
  powerdns-recursor:
    image: powerdns/pdns-recursor-51
    container_name: powerdns-recursor
    ports:
      - "1053:1053/udp"
      - "1053:1053/tcp"
    volumes:
      - ./powerdns/recursor.yml:/etc/powerdns/recursor.yml


and this is my config in recursor.yml
dnssec:
  log_bogus: true
incoming:
  listen:
    - 0.0.0.0:1053
    - '[::1]:1053'
  allow_from: 
    - 192.168.1.80
recursor:
  extended_resolution_errors: true
  forward_zones:
    - zone: .
      recurse: true
      forwarders:
        - 192.168.1.1
outgoing:
  source_address:
    - 0.0.0.0
logging:
  loglevel: 6

When I run dig @192.168.1.88 -p 1053 example.com I get the following response:
dig @192.168.1.88 -p 1053 example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @192.168.1.88 -p 1053 example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 43593
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
; OPT=15: 00 16 64 65 6c 65 67 61 74 69 6f 6e 20 2e ("..delegation .")
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      A

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.88#1053(192.168.1.88)
;; WHEN: Sat Dec 07 21:55:08 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58

I'm not sure why I'm getting SERVFAILs. I can ping 192.168.1.88. I'm wondering if there's something maybe I'm missing in my recursor.yml?
